# Bluetooth suddenly stopped working Ubuntu 20.04 - No default controller available

Tags: bluetooth

Bluetooth worked fine and one fine day (nothing changed), all of a sudden, it won't turn on from the top right dropdown. The label goes from off to on, but it doesn't change in Bluetooth Settings. I checked a lot of previous posts, but none of them fixed it. I powered off and went to sleep like I usually do, woke up next morning and it won't connect to my headset.

The hardware is fine because it works on Windows. On Ubuntu (20.04.1 LTS), it has stopped working and nothing have changed in my laptop. I've taken some previously suggested commands in other posts that I've seen and posted output over here.

```
rfkill list
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# show
No default controller available
[bluetooth]# devices
No default controller available
```

This says the bluetooth has been active, but that doesn't make sense.

```
systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor pre>
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-09-07 15:25:04 IST; 12min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 1342 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18918)
     Memory: 2.2M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─1342 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Sep 07 15:25:04 rkochar-HP-ZBook-Studio-G5 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth servi>
Sep 07 15:25:04 rkochar-HP-ZBook-Studio-G5 bluetoothd[1342]: Bluetooth daemon 5>
Sep 07 15:25:04 rkochar-HP-ZBook-Studio-G5 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth servic>
Sep 07 15:25:04 rkochar-HP-ZBook-Studio-G5 bluetoothd[1342]: Starting SDP server
Sep 07 15:25:04 rkochar-HP-ZBook-Studio-G5 bluetoothd[1342]: Bluetooth manageme>
lines 1-16/16 (END)
```

```
hcitool dev
Devices:  #No output
```

```
dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[   11.957363] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   11.957382] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   11.957385] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   11.957387] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   11.957388] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   14.111156] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc05 tx timeout
[   14.111161] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-110)
[   14.278953] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   14.278954] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   14.278958] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

```
lsmod | grep blue
bluetooth             581632  12 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth
```

```
bt-adapter -i
**
ERROR:lib/bluez/adapter.c:165:adapter_get_dbus_object_path: assertion failed: (ADAPTER_IS(self))
Bail out! ERROR:lib/bluez/adapter.c:165:adapter_get_dbus_object_path: assertion failed: (ADAPTER_IS(self))
Aborted (core dumped)
```

```
sudo bluetoothd -d -n
bluetoothd[8710]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
bluetoothd[8710]: src/main.c:parse_config() parsing /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
bluetoothd[8710]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “DiscoverableTimeout” in group “General”
bluetoothd[8710]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “AlwaysPairable” in group “General”
bluetoothd[8710]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “PairableTimeout” in group “General”
bluetoothd[8710]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “Privacy” in group “General”
bluetoothd[8710]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “Name” in group “General”
bluetoothd[8710]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “Class” in group “General”
bluetoothd[8710]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “DeviceID” in group “General”
bluetoothd[8710]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “ReverseServiceDiscovery” in group “General”
bluetoothd[8710]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have group “GATT”
bluetoothd[8710]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have group “GATT”
bluetoothd[8710]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have group “GATT”
D-Bus setup failed: Name already in use
bluetoothd[8710]: Unable to get on D-Bus
```

I have seen previous posts suggesting:

```
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth.service
sudo systemctl start bluetooth.service
```

This didn't help, it's already added (groupadd) because it previously worked and I checked again.

`rfkill unblock bluetooth` won't work, because `rfkill list` says nothing is blocked.

Just to re-iterate, it previously worked fine (for over a year) and it still works fine on Windows. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82CFb.jpg) is a screenshot of Bluetooth Settings if it's of any use.

I appreciate any and all help! Please let me know if more information is needed or something is unclear.

Comment: Reboot fixed it.

Comment: I have the exact same problem as the OP, but numerous reboots have _not_ fixed it. I don't have windows installed, though, so I cannot test that. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Update this solved it for now: Go into BIOS => disable bluetooth => reboot into BIOS again => enable bluetooth => reboot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Reboot fixed the problem (for me) and like somebody else said choose an older kernel which again requires reboot.

Answer (score 2):

After all approaches failed, I had success with these steps (like @DNF suggested):

- disable wifi/bluetooth card in UEFI
- start ubuntu
- shutdown
- enable it again

I'm using a Lenovo Ideapad C340-14API with Ubuntu 21.10.

Comment: How do you disable/enable wifi/bluetooth card in UEFI?

Comment: @deanresin that depends on your mainboard manufacturer and version. You should look into the manual for your hardware to learn how to boot into UEFI. Then, you can search through all the menus if there is a toggle for on-board bluetooth or similar.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue. I rebooted and when grub came up, I chose an older kernel, and it was fixed. IDK why this is happening, but I assume it has something to do with one of the kernel updates recently for me. The problematic kernel version is 5.4.0-47-generic

Comment: That's interesting, reboot fixed it for me.

Comment: what specific kernel version is working on to you? I have the same issue

Comment: @isemaj I'm currently using  5.4.0-77-generic. BT has worked fine for quite some time. You should tag me otherwise I don't get an alert.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue!

Luckily, I found that this has got something to do with the **Automatic Login** feature (or Keyrings?). I disabled Automatic Login and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me without the need to restart
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169931/bluetoothctl-no-default-controller-available-despite-being-unblocked

```
 sudo rmmod btusb btintel
 sudo modprobe btusb btintel
 sudo service bluetooth restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I have MSI click bios 5 and for me this solution from MSI forum was working

> "So easy fix has been found turn off PC and unplug PSU and wait 10
> minutes Hold down Power button on PC for 10 seconds during the 10
> minute power off, Plug back in and turn on PSU and boot Bluetooth
> should now be back"

Comment: Why does a simple reboot not work?

Comment: @rkochar [there](https://superuser.com/questions/85355/pulling-the-plug-out-for-10-seconds) is an part of answer to your question

Answer (score -1):

Restart works but instead of restarting the pc just run the below command

```
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```

Bluetooth will start working.